# Debian 9 - libicu60 dependency while trying to install php7.0-intl

Tags: php, debian, unicode, i18n

The title says it all... I'm trying to install the php intl extension on Debian 9 and get the following error :

```
php7.0-intl : Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
```

Debian repo says libicu60 is experimental and buggy... has anyone overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`php7.0-intl`, according to the [Official Debian Stretch packages section](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php7.0-intl), and my tests on a Debian 9 machine, requires `libicu57` as dependency.

I'd guys you either have Debian Sid repositories in your source lists, or other 3rd party repositories, which offers a newer version of the package (not `7.0.27-0+deb9u1` one which is in Debian Stretch sources).

You can see which repository has and offers `php7.0-intl` with:

`sudo apt-cache showpkg php7.0-intl`

Adjust your sources and install `7.0.27-0+deb9u1` (if it fits your requirements of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's true that I'm using Ondrej PHP packages in order to be able to have php 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 co-existing on my machine... I found this that seems to address this problem : https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/install-intl-php-7-1-extension-in-a-php-multiple-version-server.75406/ but I haven't found a solution yet